# CSS nth-child(odd) not working in table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

my situation

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="test">a</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><span class="test">a</span></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><span class="test">a</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><span class="test">a</span></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

I try use this in CSS

```
table tr td span:nth-child(odd) {
    color: red;
}
```

But not working... any ideas? I need only span change color

Comment: probably be cause you need to select odd rows not spans. i.e. `table tr:nth-child(odd) td span`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gf9116kL/